# HTML tags in WordPress file "functions.php"

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to insert some HTML tags in a PHP variable, but it results in the PHP variable value only.

It gets the `the_subtitle()` value and inserts it in the PHP variable and finally adds it to the first part of `$content`. Why doesn't the HTML tags?

My code:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_before' , 20 );

function add_before($content) {
    if ( the_subtitle() ){
        $custom_content = '<h2 class="subtitlessss">' . the_subtitle() . '</h2><br>';
    }
    $content = $custom_content . $content;
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: You haven't shown enough code to tell what is happening.

Comment: all things is that <h2> tag in line 4 doesnt show in $custom_content value...

Comment: `the_subtitle()` isn't a native WP function. Please post code for that function

Comment: it is the shortcode of this plugin:  https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-subtitle/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're modifying the output of `the_content()` by using a filter. Your callback should return a value. However, the function you're using is going to output your subtitle rather than return it.

According to the plugin documentation it works in the same way as WordPress' `the_title()`. Initially I thought `get_the_subtitle()` would be more appropriate. However, that isn't the case. Tell `the_subtitle()` not to output instead (third argument).

```
function add_before( $content ) {

    // Check if the subtitle has been set and assign the value to $subtitle
    // Saves us having to call the same function again.
    if ( $subtitle = the_subtitle( '<h2 class="subtitlessss">', '</h2><br />', false ) ) {

        // Prepend to the content.
        $content = $subtitle . $content;
    }

    // ALWAYS return content.
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_before', 20 );
```

Comment: thank you, i tried your code, but the subtitle doesnt appears too, my mean nothing shown above the post content after inserted your code to functions.php...

Comment: My code skipped your call to `add_filter`, you kept that in right?

Comment: Yes , I copied the whole of your code in my functions.php... Thanks

Comment: While removing your old code but keeping add filter?

Comment: Yes, exactly i deleted the whole of old code and replaced the whole of your code...

Comment: To avoid confusion I've simply added the filter into my code. If that doesn't work then your problem is either you aren't using `the_content` for the output, the filter isn't being called, or there's an issue with the subtitle. E.g. it hasn't been set or a bug in the plugin

Answer (score 0):

The code you have will *always* run this line:

```
$content = $custom_content . $content;
```

Could that be the issue? Try only modifying $content if the_subtitle() returns a true value, like this:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_before', 20 );

function add_before( $content ) {

  if ( the_subtitle() ) {
    $custom_content = '<h2 class="subtitlessss">' . the_subtitle() . '</h2><br>';
    $content = $custom_content . $content;
  }

  return $content;
}
```

If you are only seeing the value of $content as your code stands currently, then that means the_subtitle() isn't returning a true value so there is no value in $custom_content. This *should* throw a ***Notice: Undefined variable*** message. Does your wp-config have this line in it?

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

**After researching the_subtitle()**

OK, so it seems like the_subtitle() takes the same parameters as the native WordPress function the_title as the documentation says [here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-subtitle/):

> Parameters Just like WP's built-in the_title() method,
> the_subtitle() tag accepts three parameters:
>
> $before (string) Text to place before the subtitle. Defaults to "".
>
> $after (string) Text to place after the subtitle. Defaults to "".

Therefore, if you want HTML to come before and after *the_subtitle*, pass it as a parameter:

```
the_subtitle( '<h2 class="subtitlessss">','</h2><br>' );
```

**To check if the function exists**

Also, maybe we should be checking if the_subtitle exists instead of calling it in the if statement? Like so:

```
if ( function_exists( 'the_subtitle' ) )
```

The updated code for the entire excerpt would be this:

```
<?php

  add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_before', 20 );

  function add_before( $content ) {

    if ( function_exists( 'the_subtitle' ) ) {
      $custom_content = the_subtitle( '<h2 class="subtitlessss">','</h2><br>' );
      $content = $custom_content . $content;
    }
    return $content;
  }
```

Comment: the_subtitle has a true value and shown in result, but html tags doesnt show, i tried your code but it doesnt work...thanks

Comment: OK, I don't have the plugin that has the_subtitle() function, so I just changed that to TRUE and this ran fine on the twentyseventeen theme. I got an <h2> element with the class subtitlesssss and some content I made up. Are you sure the_content() is being called on the page that you want this html to appear on?

Comment: it is the shortcode of this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-subtitle/     yes i am sure, because when i insert this code in functions.php, the sub title value shown at above of the post, and when i delete this code, it doesnt show, that means this code retrive the subtitle correctly, but i dont know why the html tag has been trimed...

Comment: Ah OK, it seems like you need to add the HTML INSIDE the function call to the_subtitle, just like you would in the native WP the_title function. I'll update my answer to show you.

Comment: thank you, i tried your code but the problem already exsist...! still html tags doesnt appears...

Comment: Maybe you need to test that the_subtitle exists first? Check my revision.

Comment: Thank you so much, your code worked great, and also @Nathan Dawson wrote a code that works, and because of that his code is shortest and have comments i choose it as best answer (it is fast for readers to solve there issue)... Thank you very very much Daniel.Schroeder

Comment: how to can i add html tag here then 
'$tabs['reviews']['title'] = 'Reviews ('.$check_product_review_count.');'

i want to add ''$tabs['reviews']['title'] = 'Reviews <span>('.$check_product_review_count.')</span>;'   it is print with tag